# Reference assembly in sqlproj not being deployed to server

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr, visual-studio-2013, database-projects

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Database Project which takes [a modified version](https://fastjson.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/zippy1981/SqlClr/contribution/6596) of [fastJSON](https://fastjson.codeplex.com/) as a reference. I selected Generate DDL in the reference properties as shown in this screenshot:

[image: fastJSON property panel]

And in the .sqlproj msbuild file:

```
<Reference Include="fastJSON">
  <HintPath>..\..\fastjson\output\net40\fastJSON.dll</HintPath>
  <GenerateSqlClrDdl>True</GenerateSqlClrDdl>
</Reference>
```

However bin/debug/Project.sql does not contain a line for `CREATE ASSEMBLY fastJSON . . .`. Adding the assembly manually works and my project will then deploy and run. What do I do to get Visual Studio to deploy my assembly?

Comment: Hmmm... ours is set to `False`, and `Model Aware` is set to `True`, and we get a `CREATE ASSEMBLY` in the output. Maybe try those settings and see what happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>I played around a bit to figure out what these settings do... when I commented, I only mentioned what our settings are without understanding them; I'm not the project lead for our migration to Database Projects, so I wasn't familiar with the minutiae of this stuff.</sup>

The `Model Aware` property needs to be set to `True`.

This property is poorly documented, but from my understanding, enabling it will expose the objects within the assembly to the database model so they can be used in the SQLCLR wrappers (i.e., `CREATE ... EXTERNAL ...`) and the references can be resolved. If the project doesn't include these objects in the model, there's no way they'll be scripted in the output. Also, if there's a reference to an object in the assembly and this property is set to `False`, the project will fail to build.

The `Generate Sql Script` property I mentioned is in a similar state of documentation. This controls whether the publicly visible members in the assembly are *automatically* scripted into the output. We have it disabled to retain the flexibility of renaming the SQLCLR wrappers and selectively including only the objects we need. Which way you set this is up to your discretion.

Hopefully that helps the public documentation of these properties!

Comment: Thanks for this Jon!  It fixed my "unable to resolve token" error.

Comment: Where exactly is "Model Aware" set to true?

Comment: `Model Aware` and other properties can be set by right-clicking on the referenced DLL and selecting `Properties`.